# Able to get Facebook comments with FQL and Graph App but both present a problem

Tags: graph, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am working on a little mobile app for facebook and have been studying the Facebook Api's for weeks now.

My problem I need help with is comments, I have my app retrieving them via post_id/comments?access_token=****&limit=10 but the problem with this way is that the comments are being sent oldest first, so if i wanted to get the newest comments and there were 200 comments i'd have to call the api because of pagination 19 times to get the most recent. Is there any way of telling the graph api to send the newest comments first? I really want to avoid having to get all the comments at once just to sort them myself - sometimes there are over 2000 comments.

I did a little experimenting with fql last night and found I was able to specify ORDER BY time in the query and also LIMIT and less than time to do my own kind of pagination. The problem with this way is that the person name (who had made the comment) isn't returned, only an id for that person. Please correct me if im wrong but that would then mean having to make a call to the api to find out the name of the commenter for each comment made on a post - again sometimes over 2000. I think this is not a solution for mobile.

I just want my app to show comments newest first. Please can any one of any advice?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/

Comment: this is what i got working last night api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=2227470867|2.kL_fpEu5X_wDcYYvTgydYA__.3600.1299542400-100001791466540|UAreV-aZV76vt747XUWgZ05DkQ4&query=select%20post_id,%20reply_xid,%20time,%20text,%20username,%20fromid%20from%20comment%20where%20post_id%20=%20'114197465260262_209529412393733' %20ORDER%20BY%20time%20desc%20 LIMIT%203&format=json Woud you be so kind as to give me a pratical example of how I could get the name of the poster this way please?

Comment: I have been trying to solve this myself with the help of your point in the right direction. how i put my queries together. Can I create a json array of queries in a get like api.facebook.com/method/fql.multiquery?access_token=***&queries=[{query1=select%20post_id,%20reply_xid,%20time,%20text,%20username,%20fromid%20from%20comment%20where%20post_id%20=%20'114197465260262_209529412393733'}, {query2=SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #query1)%20ORDER%20BY%20time%20desc%20 LIMIT%203}]&format=json or does it have to be in a post call to the api?

Comment: its GET as far as i know.. when you get the 2 resulting arrays you just look up the id from 1 result in the array in 2 result yes ?

Comment: thanks for your help, I understand the logic but not the syntax(building the url) I got to this but it is still looking for parameter "queries" /method/fql.multiquery?access_token=**&"queries":[{"query1" : "select%20post_id,%20reply_xid,%20time,%20text,%20username,%20fromid%20from%20comment%20where%20post_id%20=%20'114197465260262_209529412393733'"}, {"query2":"SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #query1)%20ORDER%20BY%20time%20desc%20 LIMIT%203"}]&format=json, due to lack of documentation i might have to go with keeping the comments coming in oldest first :(

Comment: &"queries": - nonono :P queries is a GET parameter.. and drop the `[ ]` like this : `{"query1":"12341234","query2":"123123123"}` (i think)

Comment: ill give that a try - thanks again n00b for your time. Ill get back to you with the results for others if successful. I am currently trying to suss out another major issue with my app - determine if user likes a post. Going to start a new thred.